# How to convert datatype of all the columns of a pandas dataframe to string

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have tried multiple ways to achieve this for ex:
inputpd = pd.DataFrame(inputpd.columns,dtype=str)

But it does not work. sorry for asking this question as i am beginner to spark.

Comment: Why the `pyspark` tag (and the reference to Spark) if it is a pandas dataframe? Or is it a *Spark* dataframe...??

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I think it is:

```
df = df.applymap(str)
```

df is your dataframe.